# MySQL: Cannot insert in a MySQL View

Tags: php, mysql, database, view, insert

I am having an issue. I researched but I did not get solution.

I am trying to insert in a mysql VIEW but i am getting following error:

```
Can not modify more than one base table through a join view 'my_view'
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO  `aosship`.`products_inventory` (

`products_id` ,
`inventory_id` ,
`parent_id` ,
`qty_on_stock` ,
`inventory_date` ,
`expiration_date` ,
`supplier_id` ,
`qty_in_back_order` ,
`location_id` ,
`product_id` ,
`tax` ,
`qty` ,
`upc` ,
`product_name` ,
`description` ,
`ebt` ,
`wic` ,
`discontinued` ,
`reorder_point` ,
`reorder_qty` ,
`taxable` ,
`time_stamp` ,
`product_control` ,
`price` ,
`catagory_name` ,
`temp_product` ,
`cost`
)
VALUES (
'00000000000',  '0',  '1',  '1',  '2014-01-18 00:00:00',  '2014-01-18',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '2014-01-18 00:00:00',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1',  '1'
)
```

Query to Create view:

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `aosship`.`products_inventory` AS
    select 
        `aosship`.`products`.`ID` AS `products_id`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`ID` AS `inventory_id`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`parent_id` AS `parent_id`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`qty_on_stock` AS `qty_on_stock`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`inventory_date` AS `inventory_date`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`expiration_date` AS `expiration_date`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`supplier_id` AS `supplier_id`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`qty_in_back_order` AS `qty_in_back_order`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`location_id` AS `location_id`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`tax` AS `tax`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`qty` AS `qty`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`upc` AS `upc`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`product_name` AS `product_name`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`description` AS `description`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`ebt` AS `ebt`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`wic` AS `wic`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`discontinued` AS `discontinued`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`reorder_point` AS `reorder_point`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`reorder_qty` AS `reorder_qty`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`taxable` AS `taxable`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`time_stamp` AS `time_stamp`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`product_control` AS `product_control`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`price` AS `price`,
        `aosship`.`inventory`.`catagory_name` AS `catagory_name`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`temp_product` AS `temp_product`,
        `aosship`.`products`.`cost` AS `cost`
    from
        (`aosship`.`inventory`
        join `aosship`.`products` ON ((`aosship`.`inventory`.`product_id` = `aosship`.`products`.`ID`)))
```

Please guide me how can I fix this issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what query have you applied?

Comment: I edited and added query so please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

With a VIEW, you can only update one table at a time.

You might look into **stored procedures** if you want to update multiple tables with one query.

Comment: But please check my query above in my question. It is inserting in just one table. I am not updating multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used joins for creating view , and created view contains all the columns in the view  tables
    then  you can use two insert statement for inserting into view tables.

Comment: But I am not using two insert statements. I am using just single statement to insert.

Comment: I already inserted my Query in my question so please check that.

Comment: But you have submitted only insert query ,not create view query?

Comment: Ok i just submitted the query to Create View. so please check that